# How can I play Starcraft 2 under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: starcraft-2, linux, ubuntu

Unfortunately, I only have a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 as operating system. I'd still love to play a round of Starcrft II for sake of old times. I already tried to follow the "walk-through" from this site: https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/5w0wyv/how_to_play_sc2_on_linux_a_full_walk_through/

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, as my system - and apparently my Wine installation - is 64 bit, while the battle.net executable requires 32 bit. Mind you, I am not a very experienced Linux user, nor a gamer, nor do I have any experience with Wine. So, the question is: Is there an idiot-proof way to play Starcraft 2 in my situation? I also tried to install the thing in my Windows 7 Professional SP1 installation that I have within a VirtualBox, but this didn't work either...

Comment: Try https://lutris.net/games/starcraft-ii/